# How do I display a button only when a row is selected in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if, ngx-datatable

I have added an extra column to a table for a button to export a row from my table. I’m trying to make it so that button is only displayed for the selected row. (When you haven’t selected any rows there is no button to export the row but when you have selected a row there is a button to export the selected row but only on the row you have selected). I’ve been trying to use ngif but am new to angular so haven’t been able to figure out a solution.

** HTML CODE: **

```
<button type=“button” class=“btn” (click)=export()>Export</button>
```

Comment: Could you maybe add some details? Adding the typescript code would also help because we don't know how the selected rows are decided.

Comment: you use a variable called, e.g. "selectedIndex" that get the value of the row selected or -1 if there're no row selected. If you use a *ngFor use an index so in row you has `(click)="selectedIndex=selectedIndex==i?-1:i"` and a *ngIf make the work to show the button or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```html
HTML:

<button *ngIf="selected" type=“button” class=“btn” (click)=export()>Export</button>

TS:

Selected:Boolean=false;

selecteddrow(){
//some condition to for selecting the row.
this.selected=true;

}
```